# How can I getting word count for all PDF Files under a folder in Mac OS or Windows 10

Tags: windows, macos, pdf, word-count

I know some way to getting word count for a single PDF Files, but I have a folder which contains 500+ PDF files so I would like to know if there is a faster way to get the word count for all of them without opening every single file and do the copy past stuff like that.

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.5, If there is a solution for Windows 10 that also fine for me.

Comment: Please show your method for a single file.

Answer (score 0):

I just launched following command on my Windows machine:

```
Prompt>dir *.txt /S
```

There was an enormous output, and at the end, there was:

```
     Total Files Listed:
            3620 File(s)     93.074.638 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  410.585.006.080 bytes free
```

**Edit after first comment**
PDF is a format, which is made to be human-readable, not computer-readable, so doing some parsing and making some calculations on it, just using some simple computer commands, I don't believe it is even possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to get word count, not size cont

Comment: @Rock: I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdfgrep` which you can install with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install pdfgrep
```

Then your command to count the words in all the files will be:

```
pdfgrep -c -P  "\b.*\b"  *.pdf
```

**Sample Output**

```
Arduino Wireless Communication With the HC-12.pdf:512
sample.pdf:0
simple.pdf:4
text.pdf:22
```

The `-P` means to use `PCRE`, or *"Perl Compatible Regular Expressions"* wherein `\b` signifies a word boundary - i.e. the start or end of a word.